# can't see Direct3D swapChainPanel image when using Graphics debuging in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, direct3d, sharpdx

I'm running an UWP C# application (a game) using xaml swapChainPanel to render my Direct3D frame in visual studio 2019. I'm using SharpDx for rendering code.

Everything works fine when I debug my application.

When I run the Visual studio 2019 graphics Debugger (start graphics debugging), I can't see my swapChainPanel Direct3D image, it just does not show on screen. Everything else works fine.

If I capture the frame, it works, I can see the taken capture, and can debug the rendering pipeline, but I still can't see the live view, which is not very convenient when I need to go to a specific location in game to debug graphics...

I've updated my nvidia drivers already, and just took the latest visual studio 2019 update (currently using visual studio community 2019 16.5.4) and targetting windows 10 1903

Any idea on what may not work ?
Thanks